# Get a summary row of UNION select of multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `name` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `name` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `C` (
  `name` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And I have the query like

```
insert into A values ('foo', 1);
insert into B values ('bar', 2);
insert into C values ('ccc', 3);

select * from A where name = 'foo'
UNION 
select * from B where name = 'bar'
UNION 
select * from C where name = 'ccc';
```

Which return all the rows in table A,B,C.

I want to add a summary row (last row), at the end of this query, which is like

```
foo 1
bar 2
ccc 3
all 6
```

What would be the easiest way instead of duplicating all the sql to sum again?

Comment: The simplest idea would be to not have 3 apparently identically structured tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY` with `ROLLUP` seems viable here:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(name, 'all') AS name, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM A WHERE name = 'foo'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM B WHERE name = 'bar'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM C WHERE name = 'ccc'
) t
GROUP BY name WITH ROLLUP;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, that's what exactly I wanted.